# Nothing Returning When Using rvest and xpath on an html page

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, pipe, rvest

i'm using xpath and rvest for scraping an htm page. Other examples of rvest work well with pipelines, but for this particular script nothing is returned.

```
    webpage <- read_html("https://www.sec.gov/litigation/admin/34-45135.htm")
    whomst <- webpage %>% html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/font/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/p[2]')
```

What is returned is :

```
   {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Here is a screenshot of the page and the corresponding html

[image: Screengrab]

And here's the page that I'm on: https://www.sec.gov/litigation/admin/34-45135.htm. I'm trying to extract the words, "PINNACLE HOLDINGS, INC."

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes chrome tool doesn't give accurate xpath or css, you need to try by yourself, this selector works:

```
webpage %>% html_nodes("td > p:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text()
```

result:

```
[1] "PINNACLE HOLDINGS, INC.,   \n
```